# django - speeding up model object creation

Tags: django

I have several files that are being parsed and loaded into the django 1.7.7 database.
Here is the gist of it:

```
# models.py
class Bookstore(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Bookstore)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.store)

# the code for writing to the db:
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for i in range(100):
            bs = Bookstore.objects.create(name='x')
            for j in range(10):
                print 'creating...'
                Book.objects.create(title='hi', store=bs)
```

The problem is that the actual content is large and it takes 50 minutes to load the files into the db.
How can I speed this up?

I tried parallelizing it with this code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def create_books(store):
    for j in range(100):
        print 'creating...'
        Book.objects.create(title='hi', store=store)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        stores = []
        for i in range(2):
            stores.append(Bookstore.objects.create(name='x'))
        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        func = partial(create_books)
        data = pool.map(func, stores)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

using postgres db which has a thread-safe write operation.
I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "~django_sample_parallel_create/myapp/myapp/management/commands/parse.py", line 20, in handle
    data = pool.map(func, stores)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: error with no message from the libpq
```

I've also tried bulk_create:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        key = 1
        for i in range(100):
            bs = Bookstore.objects.create(name='x')
            books = []
            for j in range(100):
                books.append(Book.objects.create(pk=key, title='hi', store=bs))
                key += 1
            Book.objects.bulk_create(books)
```

which fails:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "myapp_book_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1) already exists.
```

I tried deleting all the data to ensure that the keys do not collide. Also tried syncing up the postgres keys.
It just fails and yet seems to have created all the objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace

```
books.append(Book.objects.create(...))
```

with

```
books.append(Book(title='hi', store=bs))
```

Comment: Great. It's working and according to my simulated sample, bulk_create sped things up by 20 times!